# Linked List with a pointer to a array of char

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list whose elements are of type

```
typedef struct List * News;
struct List
    {
         char * Text;
         News NextN;
    };
```

In the main function I declared an array of type News as follows

```
News PTH[50];
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
         PTH[i] = (News) malloc(sizeof(struct List));
         PTH[i] -> Text = NULL;
         PTH[i] -> NextN = NULL;
    }
```

I added new nodes in the beginning of the list with

```
if ( PTH[i] -> Text == NULL)
    PTH[i] -> Text = msg;
else 
    {
        t -> Text = msg;
        t -> NextN = PTH[i];
        PTH[i] = t;
    }
```

Where `msg` is a array of char of length 2000; and and then tried to print the texts apointed by `PTH[i] -> Text` with

```
p = PTH[i];
if (p -> Text != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", p -> Text);
        p = p -> NextN;
    }
while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", p -> Text);
        p = p -> NextN;
    }
}
```

This algorithm only add one node. The error is how I define the `PTH` or is there an error in how I put nodes in the list.

Comment: We can assume the typedef for `News` is *before* the `List` structure definition, right? Because as written, this won't compile. Further, `sizeof(struct News)` ? There is no `struct News`, so that won't compile regardless. Kindly post the *real* code in *compilable* form.

Comment: @WhozCraig, sorry, I edit the errors. They are not in the my program. My program is over 200 lines long and in portuguese, do I post it (The other parts are work fine)?

Comment: @claptrap each PTH[i] correspond to an news agency, and the nodes are the news, organized by the time of arriving.

Comment: @PauloHenrique ok i think i understand now, you want read texts and set them in the vector if there is previously a text you want to add a new node - so its an array of linked lists? otherwise it seems superfluous to have a link between each node when you anyway can just get the next in the array.

Comment: @claptrap yes. And after, print them in the screen, in order.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you please make it clear? What is your output, and what did you expect?

Comment: What does the `i` refer to in your third and fourth blocks of code?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves, the program keeps receiving messages. the job is organize these messages in the PTH by the name, i.e, each PTH[i] is a linked list that will contain messages from the agency i. I cannot put more than one message in the linked list.

Comment: @PauloHenrique I see. From what you said, I think it's a string copy issue. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `msg` is a buffer you use to receive new data, you have to be careful with this statement:

```
PTH[i] -> Text = msg;
```

Since `msg` is a pointer to `char`, the assignment will not copy the characters sequence; instead, it will just make `PTH[i]->Text` point to the same location as `msg`. This is problematic if you change the contents in `msg` - the changes are, of course, reflected back in every `PTH[i]->Text` for which the assignment was made, namely, every node that you ever added. Probably, not quite what you want. This is why it seems like you can only handle one node at a time. They all get the same text, because they all point to the same memory location.

You should use `strcpy` instead:

```
strcpy(PTH[i]->Text, msg);
```

Don't forget to include `string.h`.

This assumes that `PTH[i]->Text` is already allocated. You might want to use `strncpy` if there is a chance that `msg` exceeds 2000 characters, to avoid buffer overflows.

If you didn't alloc space for `PTH[i]->Text`, you could allocate exactly `strlen(msg)+1` positions for `PTH[i]->Text` and then use `strcpy` safely. Or you could use `strdup`, also declared in `string.h`, which has exactly this behavior:

```
PTH[i]->Text = strdup(msg);
```

Comment: can I copy the content of `msg` to the pointer `PTH[i] -> Text` ?

Comment: @PauloHenrique Did you alloced space for `PTH[i]->Text`? e.g. `PTH[i]->Text = malloc(...)`

Comment: NO, I did alloced for the `PTH` only.

Comment: Then you can't copy directly before allocating memory for `PTH[i]->Text`. You can use `strdup` (string duplicate) to do that for you. I updated my answer, check it. It's as simple as: `PTH[i]->Text = strdup(msg);`

Answer (score 2):

maybe it is something like this you are after:

```
if ( PTH[i]->Text == NULL )
{
  PTH[i]->Text = msg;
}
else // first create node, then append by first finding the last node
{
  News it = NULL;
  News t = malloc( sizeof(struct List));
  t->Text = msg;
  t->NextN = NULL;

  for ( it = PTH[i]->NextN; it != NULL; it = it->NextN)
  {
    ;
  }
  it->NextN = t;
}
```

Comment: I corrected that, these errors are not in my original program.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for ( it = PTH[i]->NextN; it->NextN != NULL; it = it->NextN)` ?